# SQL error near 'GROUP BY u.id ORDER BY u.user ASC LIMIT 0,100' at line 1

Tags: mysql

I need to grab all the groups a user is in and put them together as one string in order to be abble to search by terms using like statement. I am not sure whats the problem with my query ... no matter how long I look at it, I don't see what the problem is...

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'GROUP BY u.id ORDER BY u.user ASC LIMIT 0,100' at line 1

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    u.user AS USER,
    CONCAT(u.prenom, ' ', u.nom) AS nom,
    GROUP_CONCAT(g.titre SEPARATOR ', ') AS gtitre,
    e.nom AS etablissement,
    u.bloque,
    u.date_invitation,
    u.completed
FROM
    _USER u
LEFT JOIN ETABLISSEMENT_USER AS eu
ON
    eu.id_user = u.id
LEFT JOIN ETABLISSEMENT AS e
ON
    e.id = eu.id_etablissement
LEFT JOIN ETABLISSEMENT_USER AS eu2
ON
    eu2.id_user = u.id
LEFT JOIN ETABLISSEMENT AS e2
ON
    e2.id = eu2.id_etablissement
LEFT JOIN _USER_GROUPS AS ug
ON
    ug.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN _GROUPS AS g
ON
    g.id = ug.group_id
WHERE
    (
        (
        SELECT
            MIN(g.ordre)
        FROM
            `_GROUPS` g
        JOIN `_USER_GROUPS` UG ON
            g.id = UG.group_id
        WHERE
            UG.user_id = u.id
    ) >= 1 OR(
    SELECT
        MIN(UG.group_id)
    FROM
        `_USER_GROUPS` UG
    WHERE
        UG.user_id = u.id
) IS NULL
    ) AND(u.innactif = 0)
HAVING
    gtitre LIKE '%coord%'
GROUP BY
    u.id
ORDER BY
    u.user ASC
LIMIT 0, 100
```

If I remove the HAVING gtitre LIKE '%coord%' from the above it all works fine ...

How can I filter my users based on if there group contains or not the searched string?

This is my table structure for the users, the hroups and the pivot table

```
CREATE TABLE `_GROUPS` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `titre` text NOT NULL,
  `ordre` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COMMENT='contient les rôles et les tâches';

CREATE TABLE `_USER` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `innactif` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `pwd` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `courriel` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `prenom` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `nom` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `mdp_recup` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `essai` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `bloque` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `expiration` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `facteur` smallint(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `authentificator` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sexe` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `telephone` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `dashboard` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `titre` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `creation` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `expiration_compte` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_principal` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_langue` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `ext` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invitation` text,
  `date_invitation` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `completed` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `afficher_site` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_programme` text,
  `id_programme_c` text,
  `ordre` int(9) NOT NULL,
  `courriel_promo` int(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE `_USER_GROUPS` (
  `user_id` int(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `group_id` int(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Comment: SQL queries follow a precise syntax - `SELECT [columns, and aggregating functions]... FROM...JOIN...ON...WHERE...GROUP BY...HAVING...ORDER BY...LIMIT...`

Comment: `u.user` is not unique in the result set. Pagination won't work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use **HAVING** after **GROUP BY**

Comment: Sorry for that guys